# "in a street" or "in the street"?

Tags: articles

I was given a picture of people going down a sidewalk. And I was asked to answer the question of where the people are right now. Do I have to use the definite article or indefinite before the word *street*? For example:

> In this picture are two women in **a**/**the** street.

I don't know exactly which street they are at right now, what I know from the picture that they are walking down the sidewalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in the street" has a particular meaning: that they are on the road and *not the sidewalk*. They are in the middle of the road, blocking traffic.

"They are in *a* street" is not a usual expression. It sounds odd.

The preposition "on" may sometimes be used:

"Which street are they *on*?"  Good.

"They are walking down the street." This is a very common expression.  It's ambiguous here whether that means "sidewalk" or "street" -  probably "sidewalk" is implied.

Answer (score 0):

If the people are on the sidewalk, then you would use "a". This is more general - if the people were standing on the road, they would be in "the" street.